# Error LNK2019 when using GetFileVersionInfoSize()

Tags: c++, mfc

I just included this bit in my already working code, but I am getting an LNK2019 error. I'll paste the error after pasting the code.

The Class CAboutDlg has:

```
public:

    CStatic m_VersionInfoCtrl;

   virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();

};
```

The Function itself:

```
BOOL CAboutDlg::OnInitDialog()

{

   CDialog::OnInitDialog();

   CString inFileName = AfxGetApp()->m_pszExeName;

   inFileName += ".exe";

   void * theVersionInfo;

   void * theFixedInfo;

   unsigned long aVersionInfoSize = GetFileVersionInfoSize ( inFileName , &aVersionInfoSize);

   CString returnString;

   if (aVersionInfoSize)

   {

   theVersionInfo = new char [aVersionInfoSize];

   GetFileVersionInfo ( inFileName, 0 , aVersionInfoSize, theVersionInfo) ;

   unsigned int aSize = 0;

   VerQueryValue( theVersionInfo , "\\" , &theFixedInfo , &aSize);

   if (theFixedInfo)

   {

   VS_FIXEDFILEINFO * aInfo = (VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *) theFixedInfo;

   DWORD dwMajorVersionMsb = HIWORD( aInfo->dwFileVersionMS );

   DWORD dwMajorVersionLsb = LOWORD( aInfo->dwFileVersionMS ); 

   DWORD dwMinorVersionMsb = HIWORD( aInfo->dwFileVersionLS );

   DWORD dwMinorVersionLsb = LOWORD( aInfo->dwFileVersionLS ); 



  returnString.Format("Version %d . %d . %d. %d",dwMajorVersionMsb,dwMajorVersionLsb,dwMinorVersionMsb,dwMinorVersionLsb);

  //memcpy(sVer,returnString.GetBuffer(),returnString.GetLength()+1);

  }

delete theVersionInfo;

   }

   m_VersionInfoCtrl.SetWindowText(returnString);

   return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control

   // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE

}
```

....

Its giving me the following three errors:

```
1.RangemasterGenerator error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _VerQueryValueA@16 referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall CAboutDlg::OnInitDialog(void)" (?OnInitDialog@CAboutDlg@@UAEHXZ)

2.RangemasterGenerator error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoA@16 referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall CAboutDlg::OnInitDialog(void)" (?OnInitDialog@CAboutDlg@@UAEHXZ)
3.RangemasterGenerator error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoSizeA@8 referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall CAboutDlg::OnInitDialog(void)" (?OnInitDialog@CAboutDlg@@UAEHXZ)
```

...
I am not able to understand what the problem is. Can anyone help please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to link against the library that contains the two functions `VerQueryValue` and `GetFileVersionInfo` - the linker doesn't know by default where to find them.

A quick search for the two functions on MSDN suggests that they're both in the system library `version.dll` and the library you want to link against is `version.lib`. Just add that to the library list in the linker properties.

Comment: I have added version.lib in my header file as:

#pragma comment(lib,"Version.lib")

How do I add the .dll file?

Comment: Are you sure that header file gets compiled? Specially the line that has given `#pragma` ?

Comment: line 11. Its after declaring my header files.

Comment: Cheers, I got it. 

Thanks Guys.

Comment: You don't have to add the .dll file - the .lib is an import library that ensures that the loader pulls in the correct .dll at runtime.

Comment: This answer is helpful because the current version of MSDN says to include `mincore.lib` which does not contain the symbols. Version.lib is still needed.

Comment: I just noticed that too "Library  Mincore.lib" not version.lib, which actually fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

The functions **[GetFileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** and **[GetFileVersionInfoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** are defined in `Version.dll` and `Version.lib` so make sure, you are liking to the appropriate libraries.

Comment: Actually a CStatic is a specific kind of MFC control, not a static member. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98kd6f7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Timo: Ahh, corrected, that was a blinder & someone up voted it! ;-)

Comment: Wait, but following the provided links I see that those functions are in `mincore.lib`. And you are right, they are in version.lib . What is wrong?

Answer (score 6):

**I am also getting same error, while upgrading the VS6.0 application to VS2012 platform.**

**a.** error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoSizeA@8 referenced in function _main

**b.** error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoA@16 referenced in function _main

**c.** error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _VerQueryValueA@16 referenced in function _main

**Resolution:**

I found that it is due to missing reference to library "Version.lib".

**a.** For VS6.0 add it to *Project Setting->Link->library modules*

**b.** For VS2012 add to *Project Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependancies*
   and add full lib path to Include directory.

Answer (score 6):

For VS2012 or 2013 add to Project Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies -> Add Version.lib

Comment: This is all that I needed to do. No need to worry about the dll, or the full path to the file,etc.